# Is there any difference between float: none and clear: none

Tags: css, css-float

I was doing a bit of stuff using float and clear. I found no difference using `float: none;` or `clear: none;` Is there any? can anybody illustrate the difference with an example

Comment: Both `float` and `clear` have a default value of `none`, so you'll see no effect of any combination unless you're overriding some value set elsewhere.

Comment: I don't know if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/QM4mm/2/, though it might complicate things depending on your knowledge of what's happening to the content in DIV Four.

Comment: @hungerstar As, the fourth div is float: none; the fourth div start with the same top position like the first div. am i right? i am thinking why the content "four-float NONE" is written below the div? can you please explain

Comment: @Shubendra I'll try. Floated elements are taken out of the normal document flow. `#four` is not floated and is a block level element, as such will take up the whole width. If it's width is smaller than it's container margin is added to make up for the missing width.  If floated elements proceed a block element, the block element will behave as if they were not there and stacking will occur.  As for the content of `#four`, it is `inline` and will wrap floated content. If the width of `#four` was 100% (or an amount larger than the floated elements) the content would be to the right of `#three`.

Comment: @Shubendra Since `#four`'s width is less than 100% and is being completely occupied by the floated `#one` it flows all the way around the right side and ends up below it. _**I hope I explained that clearly and correctly, O.o_

Comment: @hungerstar i understood why the content is coming down. your explanation was great.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Float:none;` tells the elements that you do not wish for it to float.

`Clear` tells other elements whether they should be allowed to float or not, and in the case of none, you're allowing floats on both sides. it's why when you use `clear:both;` that floating stops.

Comment: I have read these definition. i am saying that i found no difference in effect while using clear: none and float: none. can you illustrate the difference with an example.

Comment: Then there is no difference, and nothing to illustrate. Your question title asks the difference between the two properties, and that's what this answer is addressing.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/srIuf - check out when you use clear:none how the elements in the second container continue to float under the non floating element - change that to `clear:both;` and you can see how clear talks about the containing elements and float talks about individual elements.

Comment: @BoltClock There **is** a difference in effect while using `clear: none` and `float: none`. Shubhendra's comment is wrong. I've tried to illustratee the difference with examples in my answer.

Comment: @user31782: Indeed, I was making a point against the OP with my comment. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 9):

They're two totally different things.

`float` will make an element align to the left or right (the parameter) inside its parent. `float: none` does nothing, unless the element was already floating. The float element lose it's automatically filled width, and reduce it to as small as it can get.

`clear` will make sure there are no floating elements on the side you tell. If there is one, it will move down until there is none in the given direction. `clear: both` will check this for both directions.

Here's an illustration to show you what `floats` and `clears` do.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but my doubt was with `float: none` and `clear: none` not with `clear: left`

Comment: @Shubendra: None is the default value, and could only be used for overiding a previous declared clear.

Comment: Then it will just float at the grey area (if you've made it float ofcourse, but else `clear` is useless anyway).

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you didn't understand the underlying concept of what `float` does. Any value of `float` except `none` whenever assigned to a block-level element **takes that element out of the document flow**. Suppose you have two different `div` elements, one with `float:none` and the other with `clear:none`. Now the later could be either **in** the document flow or **out** of the flow of document -- depending upon its float value. I present you two examples. In the first version the Red paragraph uses `float:none` and in the second version the Red paragraph uses `clear: none`

**Red paragraph using `float:none`:**

```css
#usefloatnone
{
  border: 1px dotted black;
  background-color: red;
  width: 1050px; height: 350px;
  
  float: none;  
}

#useclearnone
{
  border: 1px dotted black;
  background-color: red;
  width: 1050px; height: 200px;
  float: right;
  
  clear: none;
}

#normal 
{
  border: 1px dotted black;
  width: 1050px; height: 100px;
}
```

```html
</style>

  </head>
  <p id="usefloatnone"> Red paragraph </p>
  <p id="normal"> Normal paragraph </p>
  <p id="normal"> Normal paragraph </p>
  <p id="normal"> Normal paragraph </p>
</html>
```

**Red paragraph using `clear:none`:**

```css
#usefloatnone
{
  border: 1px dotted black;
  background-color: red;
  width: 1050px; height: 350px;
  
  float: none;  
}

#useclearnone
{
  border: 1px dotted black;
  background-color: red;
  width: 1050px; height: 200px;
  float: right;
  
  clear: none;
}

#normal 
{
  border: 1px dotted black;
  width: 1050px; height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p id="useclearnone"> Red paragraph </p>
  <p id="normal"> Normal paragraph </p>
  <p id="normal"> Normal paragraph </p>
  <p id="normal"> Normal paragraph </p>
```

You can see the difference in effect while using `clear: none` and `float: none` now. I suggest you to first thoroughly understand the concept of `float` and `clear` [from this tutorial by w3.org community](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Floats_and_clearing). You use `clear` property upon elements when you want to clear any floating elements around/(usually left or right to) them.

Answer (score 1):

Float none stops an element to stop wraping around adjacent floating child Elements. By default all, elements have float none. 
Clear both stop element to wrap around any floating child from left or right side. 
For more details and live examples, visit my tutorial,
       http://tutorial.techaltum.com/css_float.html.