# What is the difference between float:none and clear:both?

Tags: html, css

```
<div  class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="col-sm-6 btn-submit">

    </div>
</div>
```

`.col-sm-8` and `.col-sm-6` are floated left.

What is the difference if I add `clear:both` or `float:none` to `.btn-submit`?

Below is what happens if I add `clear:both`. The height is fit the content.

[image]

Below is what happens if I add `float:none`. The content is overlapped the 
button above.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between float: none and clear: none](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153129/is-there-any-difference-between-float-none-and-clear-none)

Comment: I don't think it's duplicated. I've gone through that before I created this question. They give very general answers. And Those answers not give me enough information to understand what is really the difference.

Answer (score 1):

float:none  will tell element not to float anywhere.

clear:both will place next element on next line if any.

Same functioning.